# newtx miktex pk fonts?

Tags: miktex, newtx

My journal publisher’s class file uses newtx fonts, so I’ve tried to update my MikTeX installation. The MikTeX package manager reports that all of `newtxtt`, `newtxsf`, `minion2newtx` and `newtx` itself (only the last is new) are installed. I’ve run (as administrator and as myself) `updmap` as well as FNDB. A simple hello world file (appended) will compile and produce a dvi, but converting it to pdf or viewing it in yap or … tries to run `miktex-makepk` to make pk fonts and these fail. Compiling with pdflatex (which is what I’d really like to do) fails in the same way:

> ```
> Trying to make PK font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 at 600 DPI...
> Running miktex-makemf.exe...
> miktex-makemf: The ntx-Regular-tlf-t source file could not be found.
> Running ttf2pk.exe...
> miktex-makepk: PK font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 could not be created.
> ```

Yap->Document Properties reports that it finds:

> ```
> ntxmi, txmi in Program Files (x86)\MikTex 2.9\fonts\vf\public\newtx\...
> rtxmi and rtxptmn in Users\steve\AppData\Local\MikTex\2.9\fonts\pk\mo…
> mtxmi and ntx-Regul.. are Not loadable
> ```

My settings show the following roots

```
c:ProgramData\MikTex\2.9     [CommonData]
d:\sjs_d\Documents\localtexmf
c:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9   [CommonInstall]
```

updmap reports:

```
$ updmap --verbose | grep newt
C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/newtx: skipping, existing cache is valid: 73 fonts, 0 dirs
C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/newtxsf: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/newtxtt: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/newtx: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
```

I’m not a font guru at all. With type1 and opentype fonts, are pk fonts needed (this question no doubt reveals my ignorance)? I’m not sure, of course, whether I have all the T1 fonts here. Googling suggests I need the `.mf` files to create the pk fonts, but `.mf` files are not present in the installed packages AFAICT.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}

Hello world.

\[ Hello maths world \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I already sent you an answer to the texhax list (and I don't like such crosspostings without notices that the question has already been asked elsewhere).

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be a failure to put newtx.map in the updmap.cfg file. Following an answer on this site to manual font installation, perform the following as administrator:

a) `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`

This creates a updmap.cfg file in C:\users\steve\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\config and opened up  Notepad. [If this file already exists it will open up that existing file for further editing]. I inserted a single line:

```
Map newtx.map
```

which I saved.

b) `initexmf -u`

c) `updmap`

Pdflatex, yap etc will now find the appropriate T1 fonts. In this sense it doesn't answer the question as posed since there is no need for the PK fonts.